# I have an object of an outer class. How do I get the object of the inner class from it?

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

```
public class Class1 {

  public Class2 getClass2() {
  //How can I implement this method?
  }

  public class Class2 {
  //...
  }
}
```

I just can't get it done, even though it should only be one line of code...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What if there is no instance? What if there are three instances?

Comment: `return new Class2();`? You should really explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: There will be only one instance of each class and Class2 can not exist without Class1, that's why I use an inner class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the concept of inner classes wrong. In your example, you have a public inner class. That doesn't mean that your `Class1` has exactly one object of `Class2`. You can still create as many objects of `Class2` as you like. If you want to do this outside of `Class1` use `new Class1.Class2()`. While this is possible, it would be bad design as galovics correctly mentioned in his answer.

If what you are trying to achieve is having one object reference to a `Class2` object inside `Class1`, use a field of type `Class2` in `Class1` and a matching getter method:

```
public class Class1 {

    private Class2 class2instance = new Class2();

    public Class2 getClass2() {
        return class2instance;
    }

    private class Class2 {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this. The inner class should be used in the outer class and not elsewhere. 
If you need an instance of the inner class then it should be not an inner class.

Comment: Ok,but I have to use a given interface for an assignment which has that method...

Comment: I disagree with this answer; nested and inner classes can provide a useful way to group related classes. See, for example, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.UIResource.html (a Swing API that uses this technique).

Comment: I don't get your problem. I think you should update your snippet because if you have to use the inner class reference outside of the outer class then it must not be an inner class.

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell I said generally you should avoid using like this but there are cases where it is useful like Builder pattern.

Comment: I use those for a a maxflow algorithm. A Net (outer Class) will get a Flow (inner Class). An Inner Class makes sense because a Flow can not exist without a Net...

Answer (score 0):

Just create a getter method in the outer class like this.

```
public class Class1 {

  public Class2 getClass2() {
  //How can I implement this method?
  }

  public Class2 getClass2() {
    return new Class2();
  }

  public class Class2 {
  //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this create a new object? What if there is already one there?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class1 {
    private Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    public Class2 getClass2() {
        return class2;
    }

    public class Class2 {
    //...
    }
}
```